# Round Robin System php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, round-robin

I'm creating landing pages. All the leads that come in go to my database. I want to retrieve the leads from my database and send them out to 2 emails

for example like this

lead 1 -> my email
lead 2 -> my employee
lead 3 -> my email 
lead 4 -> my employee
lead 5 -> my email
lead 6 -> my employee

any idea how i would start? How do you recommend i setup my database?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Any code that you have tried? What have you tried? What's the input, and what's the expected output?

Comment: Store an ongoing lead count somewhere (e.g. in a database). Then you can send to `$count % 2` which will give you a `0/1` value to choose who to send the email to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use a randomizer (e.g. `mt_rand`) to generate a number between 0 (you) and 1 (your employer). If you have more employees, then just increase the maximum number.

In your database, add a column named "assignee" or anything else, and when you store the email add also the random number. For example:

```
// Number of employees, excluding you
$employees = 1;

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO emails (email, assignee) VALUES (:email, :assignee)");
$stmt->bindParam(':email', 'someone@example.com');
$stmt->bindParam(':assignee', mt_rand(0, $employees));
```

The table will then look like:

```
email                | assignee
--------------------------------
someone@example.com  |        0
--------------------------------
someone2@example.com |        1
--------------------------------
someone3@example.com |        1
```

When you select the records, those with assignee = 1 are assigned to your employee, and those with assignee = 0 are yours.

Note: this method is the simplest one. It doesn't return an exact sequence of 0-1, but if you have N emails, on the average 50% will be assigned to you and 50% to your employee (for the "Law Of Large Numbers"), so you'll have achieved your goal!

Answer (score 0):

This is distribution, the way you may want to handle this in your database is with a token column, this token column could store a 1 or 0, 1 if you were the last person to receive the lead.  The token gets passed as the person receives the lead.

Now the inherent problem of this type of approach is that in a high demand environment the read and writes, if not happening consecutively could lead to incorrect distribution of your leads.

So you may want to do something like a function or method that handles this read and token update consecutively or if your database system handles it, within the same query via a update select statement.

Another way to handle it - is to total the amount of leads distributed and always select the person that has received the least amount of leads.  There are a lot of ways to do it depending on what you are going for.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Furthermore if you have a lead, you can store your user or employee id, whatever you have stored users in, with your lead - which will allow you to see which person has received which lead.